# Does Moles work with nUnit?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moles

I have just see the [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molestutorial.pdf) mocking framework from Microsoft Research, before I spend any time looking at it, I would like to know if it will work with nUnit, or do I have to use msTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only with a [twist](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/pex/thread/b6e678b4-58fb-4f71-8464-5b357d66b213): You need to start the nunit console runner through the moles.runner.exe command line tool.

Comment: Does it work with the nUnit GUI runner and nUnit+TestDriveDotNet?

Comment: I don't think so, have a look here about TestDriven.NET: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/pex/thread/ba5899c5-b8e0-4754-81e7-5dbc93482875. If I understand that correctly, it doesn't even work with TestDriven.NET if you use MSTest.